# Scala spark dataframe keep leading zeroes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, zero

I'm reading the following csv files :

```
id,hit,name
0001,00000,foo
0002,00001,bar
0003,00150,toto
```

As a spark Dataframe with an SqlContext which give the output :

```
+--+---+----+
|id|hit|name|
+--+---+----+
|1 |0  |foo |
|2 |1  |bar |
|3 |150|toto|
+--+---+----+
```

I need to keep the leading zeros in the Dataframe.
I tried with the option "allowNumericLeadingZeros" set to true, it doesn't work.
I saw some posts saying it's an excel issue, but my issue is that the leading zeros are removing inside the Dataframe.

How can I keep the leading zeros inside the Dataframe ?

Thanks !

Comment: Will lpad work for your case? Here is the docs link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lpad-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-int-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks for the fast asnwer, I just tried with lpad and it works, but I'm not sure it's the "right" way to do it, this way I'm only adding 0.
Isn't it better if I read the csv correctly with all the leading 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

public Dataset csv(String... paths)

Loads a CSV file and returns the result as a DataFrame.
This function will go through the input once to determine the input schema if inferSchema is enabled. To avoid going through the entire data once, disable inferSchema option or specify the schema explicitly using schema.

You can set the following CSV-specific options to deal with CSV files:

- sep (default ,): sets the single character as a separator for each field and value.
- encoding (default UTF-8): decodes the CSV files by the given encoding type.
- quote (default "): sets the single character used for escaping quoted values where the separator can be part of the value. If you would like to turn off quotations, you need to set not null but an empty string. This behaviour is different form com.databricks.spark.csv.
- escape (default ): sets the single character used for escaping quotes inside an already quoted value.
- comment (default empty string): sets the single character used for skipping lines beginning with this character. By default, it is disabled.
- header (default false): uses the first line as names of columns.
- inferSchema (default false): infers the input schema automatically from data. It requires one extra pass over the data.

> - ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace (default false): defines whether or not leading whitespaces from values being read should be skipped.

- ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace (default false): defines whether or not trailing whitespaces from values being read should be skipped.
- nullValue (default empty string): sets the string representation of a null value. Since 2.0.1, this applies to all supported types including the string type.
- nanValue (default NaN): sets the string representation of a non-number" value.
  positiveInf (default Inf): sets the string representation of a positive infinity value.
- negativeInf (default -Inf): sets the string representation of a negative infinity value.
- dateFormat (default yyyy-MM-dd): sets the string that indicates a date format. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to date type.
- timestampFormat (default yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ): sets the string that indicates a timestamp format. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to timestamp type.
- java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf() and java.sql.Date.valueOf() or ISO 8601 format.
  maxColumns (default 20480): defines a hard limit of how many columns a record can have.
- maxCharsPerColumn (default 1000000): defines the maximum number of characters allowed for any given value being read.
- maxMalformedLogPerPartition (default 10): sets the maximum number of malformed rows Spark will log for each partition. Malformed records beyond this number will be ignored.
- mode (default PERMISSIVE): allows a mode for dealing with corrupt records during parsing.
- PERMISSIVE : sets other fields to null when it meets a corrupted record. When a schema is set by user, it sets null for extra fields.
- DROPMALFORMED : ignores the whole corrupted records.
  FAILFAST : throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

Parameters:

paths - (undocumented)

Returns:
(undocumented)
Since:
2.0.0

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html

Example :

```
val dataframe= sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("/FileStore/tables/1wmfde6o1508943117023/Book2.csv")

val selectedData = dataframe.select("id","hit","name")
```

Result :

```
+---+---+----+
| id|hit|name|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  0| foo|
|  2|  1| bar|
|  3|150|toto|
+---+---+----+
```

Now change   .option("inferSchema", "false")

```
val dataframe= sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "false") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("/FileStore/tables/1wmfde6o1508943117023/Book2.csv")

val selectedData = dataframe.select("id","hit","name")
```

Result :

```
+----+-----+----+
|  id|  hit|name|
+----+-----+----+
|0001|00000| foo|
|0002|00001| bar|
|0003|00150|toto|
+----+-----+----+
```

Comment: you have mentioned change header to false but you changed inferSchema to false , please look into it once

Comment: The inferSchema = true got me wrong
Thanks, now that inferSchema is false, it's working !

Answer (score 1):

You must have set InferSchema as true while reading dataframe, remove this option or set it to false

```
sparkSession.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","false").csv("path")
```

Through this option, Spark infer the schema of dataframe and set dataType according to the values found, so spark is basically inferring that **id** and **hits** columns are numeric in nature and so it is removing all the leading zeros.

For further assistance take a look at [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a `schema` for your `dataframe` and define the types as `String`s.

You can create `schema` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("id", StringType, true), StructField("hit", StringType, true), StructField("name", StringType, true)))
```

and use it in `sqlContext` as

```
val df = sqlContext.read.option("header", true).schema(schema).format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .csv("path to csv file")
```

As others answered you that the real culprit is that you might be using `.option("inferSchema", true)` which takes `id` and `hit` columns as `integer`s and leading `0`s are removed.

So you can read the csv file without `.option("inferSchema", true)` or with `schema` defined as above

I hope the answer is helpful